# Como fazer a impressão das páginas sair da forma que é vista na tela?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso fazer uma página que, quando o usuário imprima, saia exatamente como ela é vista na tela (com os estilos), estou utilizando **Bootstrap** versão 3.1.

Existe algum **plugin** em Javascript que faça isso? A solução que pensei foi ao invés de pegar o *código-fonte*, gerar um print do conteúdo, existe outras maneiras para fazer isso?

Exemplo de como fica o **StackOverflow** no modo de impressão (**Chrome**) 
[image: Print do SO]

Comment: Compartilhe conosco o trecho de HTML e CSS que deseja imprimir. Ficará mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: @EliezerBernart É uma **GridView** eu queria imprimir a cor do cabeçalho exatamente como ele é visualizado na browser. Achei a solução mas apenas para o Chrome. Acrescentei uma resposta, de uma olhada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você deseja que o estilo de impressão seja o mesmo para todas as visualizações da sua página é possível utilizar o `media="all"`.

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Caso esteja utilizando o estilo através da tag `<style>` pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
@media all {
    \** Seu css **\
}
```

Espero que lhe ajude!

*Update*

O Twitter Bootstrap traz uma pré-configuração do [@media print](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L190)

```
* {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Portanto tudo que você imprimir ficará sem cor, ou melhor, **transparente**. Altere essas configurações no seu arquivo do bootstrap, ou remova completamente e veja os resultados.

Por fim, seu navegador também precisa estar com as opções de impressão em cores habilitada na janela de **Propriedades de Impressão**:

Exemplo no Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Habilitando impressão das cores de fundo]

Comment: Como mencionei na postagem já tentei isso!

Comment: @Laerte Update!

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando achei a propriedade `-webkit-print-color-adjust` que infelizmente só funciona no **Chrome**, mas minha pergunta é focada numa solução que funcione nos principais navegadores (vou continuar pesquisando, aceito contribuições!)

```
body {
     -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Segundo a definição da **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)**: A propriedade *-webkit-print-color-adjust* é uma extensão **não padronizada do CSS**, que pode ser usado para forçar a impressão de cores e imagens de fundo em navegadores baseados no motor **WebKit**, fiz um exemplo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/S4gtA/).

No meu projeto utilizei também a propriedade `!important` para o browser sacar qual é a cor prioritária.

**Referências:**
[Force Accurate Colors When Printing Web Pages](http://demosthenes.info/blog/573/Force-Accurate-Colors-When-Printing-Web-Pages)
[How to force an element's background to be printed in Webkit](http://sashtown.de/how-to-force-an-elements-background-to-be-printed-in-webkit)
[Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253634)